# Is there a way to get folders to appear on top in Dreamweaver CC 2021?

Tags: dreamweaver

I recently updated my Dreamweaver to CC 2021 on my Mac and now the files/folders within the FTP panel don’t appear like they used to. In my previous version, along with the rest of my OS, I always had folders appear on top, then all files in alphabetical order.

In the new version of Dreamweaver, it looks like you can only sort by file type, and your system preferences of folders on top doesn’t not carry over.

Has anyone came across a way to have the folders on top of the files, and the files in alphabetical order?